# Overriding CSS in Doorkeeper gem views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am trying to modify the views that come with the Doorkeeper gem (Referred to the wiki: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-views).

I'd like the doorkeeper/authorizations/new.html.erb to use my application css. I've tried adding this line to the view:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

It still, however, uses doorkeeper's CSS. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When you run ```rails g doorkeeper:views``` and it should have created the base template at ```app/views/layouts/doorkeeper/application.html.erb```. instead of adding the css at at  ```app/views/doorkeeper/authorizations/new.html.erb```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link that you use as reference, have you modify the doorkeeper configuration file?
In my experience, I had to make a layout file, and then in `config/application.rb`, I added my layout file. I believe you can put your css file in the layout file.

As you have to modify the configuration, you have to restart the server.